# Анимация в react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Здравствуйте, начинаю заниматься web-разработкой и возник вопрос как сделать анимацию в react js и как с ней работать. Нашел англоязычную статью для меня, пока что, она не до конца понятна. Прошу помощи у тех кто занимался анимацией в react или просто понимает как это должно быть. Поскольку только начинаю заниматься web-разработкой, то,  если кто-то будет писать ответ, чтобы он был прост для понимания новичка и не профессионала. Большое Вам спасибо.

Comment: эту статью https://reactjs.org/docs/animation.html ?

Comment: Да, эту статью.